# JavaScript - Pop-Up Window opening only ONCE

Tags: javascript

Need to create a javascript that opens **a single** window.

Code:

```
document.body.onclick= function() {
    window.open(
        'www.androidhackz.blogspot.com',
        'poppage',
        'toolbars=0,
        scrollbars=1,
        location=0,
        statusbars=0,
        menubars=0,
        resizable=1,
        width=650,
        height=650,
        left = 300,
        top = 50'
    );
}
```

What should I do? This script opens every single click on the website - I want it only once.

Answer (score 1):

Add a flag that says you opened it. Check the flag, if set, than do not open it.

If it is only one time on the entire site, than means cookie or localstorage.

Comment: +1 for the only one mentioning the all important Cookie after a reload!

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0;

document.body.onclick= function(){

  if(count === 0) window.open('www.androidhackz.blogspot.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var clickedAlready = false;      

  document.body.onclick = function() {

     if (!clickedAlready) {
         window.open('www.androidhackz.blogspot.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
         clickedAlready = true;
     }

  };
```